# How to get $settings data out of CakePHP 2.0 FormAuthenticate object

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am building a RememberMe Component using the AuthComponent and would like to get the `BaseAuthenticate::$settings` data (userModel and fields) data out of the XxxxAuthenticate object so I can know what model and fields I should be dealing with, but I can't seem to figure out how to get that data back out.

Any suggestions?

Basically I need something with the same functionality as `Auth::getModel( )` or `Auth::$userModel` from Cake 1.X.

Cake- 2.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auth::$userModel still exists in 2.0.  However, you probably have to access it via the instantied object rather than statically:

```
$modelData = $this->Auth->userModel;
```

If this isn't set, then it defaults to User.

You can then get the model by looking at the first array key that is returned:

```
$modelName = key($modelData[0]);
```

Comment: It was throwing Fatal errors on `$this->Auth->getModel`, so I just assumed `$this->Auth->userModel` was invalid as well.  Thanks.