# What is AuthComponent::getModel() alternative in cakePHP2x?

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I am using a Remember Me Component. Actually, migrating a CakePHP 1.3 app to CakePHP 2x. I am stuck with this LAST PIECE of code that is RememberMeComponent.

The script which I see here to SET the cookie is :

```
function make( ) {
    $data = array(
        $this->ident_field => $this->_create_token( ),
        $this->token_field => $this->_create_token( ),
    );

    $this->Cookie->name = $this->cookie_name;
    $this->Cookie->time = $this->period;
    $this->Cookie->key = base64url_encode(implode('::', $data));
    $this->Cookie->secure = true;

    $this->Auth->getModel()->save(array($this->Auth->userModel => array_merge(array('id' => $this->Auth->user('id')), $data)), false);

}
```

and checks with :

```
function check( ) {
    $cookie = $this->Cookie->read($this->cookie_name);

    if (empty($cookie)) {
        return false;
    }

    $data = explode('::', base64url_decode($cookie));

    $user = $this->Auth->getModel( )->find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            $this->Auth->userModel.'.ident' => $data[0],
        ),
    ));

    if ( ! $user) {
        return false;
    }
```

function base64url_encode is defined in bootstrap - so, it is valid function.

Now there is line:

```
$this->Auth->getModel()->save(array($this->Auth->userModel => array_merge(array('id' => $this->Auth->user('id')), $data)), false);
```

That is giving me an error:

```
Error: Call to undefined method AuthComponent::getModel()   
File: /var/www/FlintStones/Controller/Component/RememberMeComponent.php
```

I checked [Auth Component](http://api.cakephp.org/class/auth-component) documentation but, it did not have any option where I could find the model for auth.

Thanks in advance.

PS: We cannot directly move to Auto Login (as you might have that in mind) or if you can also refer to a quick-step-by-step, please share. I might even consider that but, so far it is just to get the Auth model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue in the same component.

[How to get $settings data out of CakePHP 2.0 FormAuthenticate object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198125/how-to-get-settings-data-out-of-cakephp-2-0-formauthenticate-object)

Summary:

Use `$this->Auth->userModel` to get the model.  If the value is `null`, it will default to `'User'`.

Comment: Yes, I figured it lately too... Btw... we both were working on one project (VF) when we encountered it... Hope you remember me... :)

Comment: On my personal website?  Yes.  On the website we worked on together?  No idea, I don't work there any more.